# Google play services non multiplayer invitation challenge message

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services

I am developing a puzzle game in LibGDX that once you have finished a puzzle you can challenge a friend to beat your score in that same puzzle

This involves sending 4 variables to that friend

```
intent.putExtra("PuzzleId", puzzle.puzzle_id.toString());
        intent.putExtra("ScoreCombined", score.combinedScore);
        intent.putExtra("ScoreHints", score.hintsUsed);
        intent.putExtra("ScoreDuration", score.puzzleCompletionTime);
```

All i need to do is prompt a user via google play services that a friend has challenged them to beat this score do they want to attempt it, if they do it launches my app and loads that puzzle or even only prompts the user when they open my app manually?

Can anyone suggest a good method for accomplishing this?

Is deep linking a better method? that might only work for google+ page updates or something then they have to click a link

I have been currently attempting to go the turn based multiplayer method which has allowed me to popup a friend selection screen select a friend build the intent add my variables

```
Intent intent = Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), 1, 7, true);

        intent.putExtra("PuzzleId", puzzle.puzzle_id.toString());
        intent.putExtra("ScoreCombined", score.combinedScore);
        intent.putExtra("ScoreHints", score.hintsUsed);
        intent.putExtra("ScoreDuration", score.puzzleCompletionTime);

        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PLAYERS);
```

This successfully pops up a friend selection screen i can select multiple people and click start game
Problem 1 is when the onActivityResult is called my variables are no longer in the intent
Using this code

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Set keys = extras.keySet();
                Iterator iterate = keys.iterator();
                System.out.println("Intent Extras are");
                while (iterate.hasNext()) 
                {
                    String key = iterate.next().toString();
                    System.out.println("Extra key="+key + " value=" + extras.get(key).toString());
                }
```

My variables didn't get passed

Problem 2 now I'm getting deep into creating rooms and starting match but i don't need any of this complication i just want to send an invitation with those 4 variables then the work is over the user can either accept or not no game necessary

When trying to actually start this match it prompts the original instigator to start the turn which obviously doesn't work either i need the challenged friend to get the first turn so they can kill the multiplayer session and just retrieve my four variables

Is there an easier way to handle this? using the game start method i can get the user id for selected users and i could save the variables separately if necessary but i don't know if there is a method to just send a message to a user id? and if that would accomplish the same end result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are no easy ways to communicate via google play services. GCM and Turn or Normal game services are the only options I can find and they are extremely top heavy

I have implemented this functionality by storing the data outside of that intent as it didn't pass data

Then creating a TurnBasedMatch and setting the data there then immediately setting it to the opposing players turn

I can detect this game invitation on the other android device and pull the data from the match successfully by embedding it as a byte array

Though I haven't tried it yet when completing my game I will send the resulting data back to the originator with the results via a new turn then display them and end the match

I'm not sure if this answer will help anyone other than saying Abandon all hope heh